# Display jquery slider under content as background using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I use Bootstrap and jQuery Camera Slider (http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/). I would like to know, is it possible to insert that slider under a content.

I wanna create something like baner rotator and above it display static logo, navigation etc.

```
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="libs/images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                        ...
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>  
</header>
<figure>
    <div id="slider">
        <div id="camera_wrap">
            <div data-src="libs/images/slides/image1.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="libs/images/slides/image2.jpg"></div>    
        </div>                  
    </div>  
</figure>
```

Comment: Its possible, but what output/issue you getting?

Comment: Firstly i see logo and navigation and next slider...like insert <br> tag

Comment: I need a effect something like http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_57726/

Comment: Then your header should have css like 
header{position:fixed, top:0, z-index:99}

Comment: @Shiv There is a problem, when I do like you say, it is possible, but when i scroll down a website header is gonna slide with me ;]

Comment: @Shiv it looks like { position:absolute; } solving a problem...

Comment: yeah you can go with position:absolute